# Bootstrap Table filter by string partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm using the Bootstrap-table plugin (http://bootstraptable.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) and I'm trying to filter by tags by utilizing the method `filterby` but can't figure out how to factor in multiple tags that has to come in as a string, separated by commas.

I created an example to illustrate what I'm attempting to achieve. For simplicity,

Here's the html:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="date">Date</th>
        <th data-field="desc">Description</th>
        <th data-field="tags">Tags</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<br>
<button id="filter-general">General</button>
<button id="filter-rotation">Rotation</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [{
  "date": "2016-05-10",
  "tags": "General, Research, Rotation",
  "desc": "Nunc velit lectus, ornare vitae fringilla eget, vestibulum quis tortor."
},{
  "date": "2016-04-22",
  "tags": "General",
  "desc": "Nunc velit lectus, ornare vitae fringilla eget, vestibulum quis tortor."
},{
  "date": "2016-03-23",
  "tags": "Research, Rotation",
  "desc": "Nunc velit lectus, ornare vitae fringilla eget, vestibulum quis tortor."
},{
  "date": "2015-11-01",
  "tags": "Rotation",
  "desc": "Nunc velit lectus, ornare vitae fringilla eget, vestibulum quis tortor."
},{
  "date": "2016-08-15",
  "tags": "General, Rotation",
  "desc": "Nunc velit lectus, ornare vitae fringilla eget, vestibulum quis tortor."
}];

$(function() {
  $table = $('#table');
  $table.bootstrapTable({
    data: data
  });

  $('#clear').click(function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {});
  });

  $('#filter-general').click(function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
      tags: "General"
    });
  });

  $('#filter-rotation').click(function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
      tags: "Rotation"
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqxwr3uL/6/

Edit: Either by `filterby` method or from one of the filter extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck using the filterBy fuction.  From the source code (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/develop/src/bootstrap-table.js):

```
var f = $.isEmptyObject(this.filterColumns) ? null : this.filterColumns;

// Check filter
this.data = f ? $.grep(this.options.data, function (item, i) {
     for (var key in f) {
        if ($.isArray(f[key]) && $.inArray(item[key], f[key]) === -1 ||
            item[key] !== f[key]) {
                return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
 }) : this.options.data;
```

where item[key] is your cell value and f[key] is your filter string.  $.inArray is looking for the complete text of the cell in your filter strings.

Comment: Do you think one of the two extensions can achieve this behaviour? Still looking into it but can't make any sense of how it could look by partial string.

Answer (score 0):

i know, old session but just change check filter part to this:

```
for (var key in f) {

    if (Array.isArray(f[key]) && !f[key].includes(item[key])) {
     return false;
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(f[key]) ){

       if(item[key].search(f[key])==-1){
         return false
       }
   }
 }
```